# What are these strange outputs in the Litecoin blockchain?

Tags: litecoin, script

I have found that there are some strange outputs in the Litecoin blockchain that pay small amounts to the scriptPubKey `736372697074`. In ASCII, this translates to "script", reminding me of how nodes used to advertise support for P2SH by putting the string "/P2SH/" within a mined blocks coinbase's scriptSig.

The outputs have very small amounts, although they are unspendable since the 'p' ASCII character happens to correspond to OP_RETURN, and seem to show up in blocks between (roughly) blocks 81,374 and 114,829.

What are these outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are from an early version of P2Pool, which mistakenly sent outputs to the literal string "script" rather than the variable `script`. This was naturally fixed, but left lying around are a number of these outputs.